# DB connection does not work in Yii cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, cron

I've followed the Yii [cron setup instruction](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/91/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii/) for configuring jobs thru invoking Commands (Run PHP in CLI (console) mode).
The cron job works as designed, yet when i address to the AR models or query SQL the script/command doesn't work.

I've set the DB connection in **config/cron.php**:

```
...
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blogandt_yiiapp',
        //mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => '...',
        'password' => '..',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'yiiapp_', 
        'class'         => 'CDbConnection'   
    ),
 ),
```

**TestCommand.php:**

```
<?php
class TestCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    public function run($args) {        
    $dateObj = new DateTime('NOW');  //date("Y-m-d");       
    $fromTime = date_format($dateObj, "Y-m-d H:m:i");
            date_modify($dateObj, '+5 days');   
    $toTime = date_format($dateObj, "Y-m-d H:m:i"); 
    $message = "Time span is from {$fromTime} to {$toTime} ";
    mail('xyz@gmail.com', 'TestCommand run', $message, '');
    
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('time', $fromTime, $toTime);  
    $notification = DocEventNotification::model()->findAll($criteria);
            // OR
    //$query = 'SELECT n.UserId, n.EventId FROM yiiapp_doc_event_notification n';
    //$query .= "WHERE (n.time BETWEEN '{$fromTime}' AND '{$toTime}') AND n.turn = '1' ";
    //$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    mail('xyz@gmail.com', 'TestCommand after DB query', $message, '');
      }
  } ?>
```

When i do not address the DB whether thru AR or directly the emails are sent, while with DB queries - are not. I've checked these AR queries in a controlller - they work fine. What's wrong?

### EDIT

Actually when querying thru `$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();` the 1st mail is being sent, while second one (after DB query) is not.

### Edit2

I put down a snippet from `cron.log`. Seems there is a problem with PDO object.

```
 2013/10/21 23:25:00 [error] [php] include(PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or       directory (/home/blogandt/domains/blogandtraffic.com/public_html/framework/YiiBase.php:427)
```

I've not included PDO support while configuring Yii.
What's solution?

Comment: try to exec manually and look at the error!

Comment: how can i exec a command if shared host does not give shell access?

Comment: probably sth with `DocEventNotification` model class

Comment: as i've said in my question, i've tryed to fetch records from `DocEventNotification` model class in controller/action with success. (the same code). So, i cannot figure out a problem...

Comment: You may try exec command in some controller in this way: `$com = TestCommand; $com->run(array());`. Or, maybe, you may see logs of cron scripts

Comment: @CreatoR, thank you for help, yet, the given syntax issued in: `Fatal error: Call to a member function run() on a non-object in <controller URI>`

Comment: You are great man.... Saved my day

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem of concatenation. Was missing a space after the n

```
$query = 'SELECT n.UserId, n.EventId FROM yiiapp_doc_event_notification n ';
$query .= "WHERE (n.time BETWEEN '{$fromTime}' AND '{$toTime}') AND n.turn = '1' ";
```

Try and tell us what happen.

Comment: i've done it with no result. Actually prior to that i've commented the second line `$query .= ...`